# Can I create a made-up mental disorder for my story?

Tags: diseases

I was thinking of creating a fictional mental disorder for one of my characters. It's something like DID (Dissociative Identity Disorder) but it's different. The similarity is that it stems from childhood trauma.

This disorder isn't just for one of my characters, there are a select few people in the story suffering from this disorder as well.

I would like to know if I were to create this (a completely made-up mental disorder) for my story, is it acceptable or is it wrong to do it? And can I communicate this to my readers through a disclaimer? (Because I'm doing this for a web-comic)

Comment: As long as you specify clearly what the disorder is, making it notably different from any existing disorders, it should be clear it is made up. Give it a non-existent name as well. When people Google it, no relevant answers should pop up, indicating it is purely fictional.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [writing.se] as it is *about* writing stories, not how to build a world.

Comment: Agreed with that this would be better over in the Writing SE.  However on the issue of the disclaimer, I would recommend a little discretion.  Don't declare that the disorder doesn't exist because in today's litigious culture, some nut job will develop your symptoms and then sue you for being insensitive to his delicate mental condition.  Better to claim that "to the best of the my knowledge, this particular disorder is purely fictional but if it does exist, my sincerest sympathies and respect to the brave souls suffering from this and all mental illnesses."

Comment: Making it up is a great idea.  It is like making up a fictional country.  When you say that people from that fictional country tend to get really stupid tattoos because their mommas make them do it, no-one will show up at your book signing in a huff.

Comment: It's called *fiction* for a reason. It's your world, your rules.

Comment: Mental disorders are very rarely, if ever, described correctly in works of fiction, and nobody ever even thought about adding a corny disclaimer. Did the *Da Vinci Code* come with a disclaimer saying that the organization called the Catholic Church in the novel has little resemblance to the real-world Catholic Church, or that the history of the Christian religion described in the novel has little to do with the actual history of the actual Christian religion? Did the *Three Musketeers* come with a disclaimer that Anne of Austria was not actually the lover of Lord Buckingham? No, they didn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Many mental disorders are nested so it may already be broadly defined**

Chances are, your disorder would likely be captured by an existing disorder. Many disorders are nowadays classified in a nested fashion, with umbrella terms encapsulating more refined definitions.

For instance Schizophrenia under DSM-5 is a broad spectrum, encapsulating specific disorders within, but all associated with types of psychosis.

There may be not be a precise label of your particular disorder, but it is still likely to be a refinement of a broader category of disorders. So you have several options available:

- Reference a broad category, and associate your disorder within that definition (eg. The characters are suffering "a type of ...")
- Create a new term within an existing category (eg. "Individuality Disorder, which is a type of Schizophrenia")
- Ignore existing classification systems, and simply label it separately, much like 'Aspergers Syndrome' was labelled prior to its now current nesting under Autism Spectrum Disorder.

If it is a fictional setting where mental illness features prominently, have a look at DSM-5 and its classification system, which can be quite complex but still attempts to define and categorise disorders in an orderly fashion.

If you do not have a classification and opt for option 2 or 3, a disclaimer may not be necessary if the work is obviously fictional beyond the "*Names, characters, business, events and incidents are the products of the author's imagination. Any resemblance to actual persons, living or dead, or actual events is purely coincidental*".